# I've got 10 upvotes for an answer, but no badge.

Tags: support, status-completed, badges

I got 10 up-votes for [this answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/275/tab-overflow-what-to-do-when-i-run-out-of-space/276#276) 11 hours ago, but still no nice answer badge.

I know that badge awarding isn't instantaneous, but I think it should have been awarded by now.

However, I've just noticed that the none of the "Nice Question/Answer", "Good Question/Answer", "Great Question/Answer" etc. badges are on the site's [badges page](https://ux.stackexchange.com/badges). Is this related?

*Some* badge scripts are working - I just got the "Scholar" badge for [this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/226/what-size-should-i-make-my-icons-so-that-people-with-some-degree-of-visual-impair).

Now also posted on [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60894/missing-badges-on-ui-stack-exchange-private-beta)

Comment: Try to ask this question on http://meta.stackoverflow.com. They deal with bugs etc. This site is for discussion on content of the parent site (UI.StackExchange.Com).

Comment: @Jouke - I know all about Meta, but as it appears to be site specific I thought I ought to raise it here first.

Comment: Okay, my bad then ;-)

Comment: @Jouke - It's OK, I've posted on Meta as well - just to be sure someone gets to see the problem. The next step will be to flag the post and hope a moderator comes by soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found some badges that were out of sync.  This should be fixed.